# Are math homework systems discussions allowed here?

Tags: discussion, homework

Are postings related to software we use: WebAssign, Aleks, MyMathLab, WileyPLus etc, allowed here? Topics would be bugs, features, educational philosophy, ... . Or should it go to general math site, or math education site, ...?

Comment: Possibly... can you give more details about what kinds of questions you are interested in asking?  Also, [matheducators.se] might be a better venue for such questions.

Comment: I noticed a major bug in WebAssign. I want to alert users and get input as to what they do about it.

Comment: That is probably not appropriate for this site.  It would likely be best to submit a bug to the managers of WebAssign.

Comment: I did, a month has passed but no resolution or acknowledgement of an issue. With the situation being what it is I was wondering about alternatives.

Comment: Such a question is not really on-topic here (and likely not really on-topic at [matheducators.se]).